# I want to clone a stable coin project in Rust but having a lot of errors

Tags: ink, parachain, substrate-contracts-node

I am facing too much errors when I clone this project, I want to create a stable coin in substrate I found this repository https://github.com/1010adigupta/ink-Stable-Coin

But after installing rust when follow all the steps to run it as mentioned in repository. I got errors in compiling . After clone the project we need to go to stable coin folder and run the command like  **cargo contract build**

Got these types of errors

ERROR: Error invoking `cargo metadata` for Cargo.toml

Caused by:
`cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating crates.io index
Updating git repository `https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts`
warning: spurious network error (3 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
error: failed to get `openbrush` as a dependency of package `stable_coin_contract v4.0.0-beta.1 (/home/blockchain/myproject/ink-Stable-Coin/contracts/stable-coin)`

```
Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `openbrush`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts?branch=main

Caused by:
  failed to fetch into: /home/blockchain/.cargo/git/db/openbrush-contracts-27b3a02a91f8eba3

Caused by:
  network failure seems to have happened
  if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  failed to resolve address for github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution; class=Net (12)
```

Comment: Try using a proxy. It's a network issue.